# elasticsearch, ngrams should cover entire query? (compound word query)

Tags: search, elasticsearch, n-gram

Suppose a user search "koreanpop"
when he really means "korean pop".

I don't think I can build a dictionary in order to recognize "korean" and "pop" as word.
I'm going to use nGram for query analyzer. (is this a horrible idea?)

I'd like to try out

```
"ko/reanpop"
"kor/eanpop"
"kore/anpop"
"korea/npop"
"korean/pop"
"koreanp/op"
```

and find out documents with both "korean/pop".
(which will be edge-ngram, min=2)

1. Is this an ok strategy in practice? 
   (I know that koreans do not use whitespaces as they should to separate words because Korean search engines support them)
2. How do I accomplish this with elasticsearch?

Comment: what is your exact usecase? How many missed spaces are you willing to accept? Which do you prioritise: space taken by the index or query speed? If index size then what you're proposing is probably your best bet (a naive implementation will be exponential though, something based on DP will probably go down to quadratic). If speed then maybe a clever use of shingle token filter might help? Depends on the exact spec.

Comment: How about combining words at index time ? E.g. for doc "korean pop hello world", you can index it into two fields, one with normal analyzer, one with two words combined: `koreanpop`, `pophello`, `helloworld`